# Deleting a suspicious malware (imklaunchagent) in Mac

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, mac, malware, virus

I have a MacBook Pro (macOS Mojave) laptop and have recently noticed a suspicious process in Activity Monitor with this name : imklaunchagent

[image]

I checked this folder:
/System/Library/Frameworks/InputMethodKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/imklaunchagent and it seems imklaunchagent and its related files cannot be removed. I tried to remove it via Terminal and this message showed up: "Operation not permitted". However, in "Security and Privacy" of "System Preferences", I chose Terminal to have full disk access, still can't delete the file and the same message appears.

I installed the free version of Combo Cleaner and it detected other viruses, none of which are imklaunchagent. Is imklaunchagent a malware? How can it be deleted?

Comment: Why do you consider this process to be suspicious?

Comment: @nohillside It seems I was wrong, this process itself is not harmful for Mac.

Answer (score 2):

You can't *(see † below)* remove that file because MacOS doesn't let you (or anyone) alter the contents of /System. Only Apple can write to that location.

MacOS does that to ensure the integrity of the OS. In other words, if it's in /System, it's part of the OS.

*† By 'can't', I mean in the normal running of your computer, unless you yourself follow a particular procedure which no active software can perform by itself as a means of corrupting your system.*

Comment: It's no problem at all (**but unwanted**) to remove the file (either by disabling SIP or booted to Recovery Mode)! IMHO it's more important to indicate that the process *imklaunchagent* itself is completely legit. It may "[h]owever oftentimes [be] targeted by dangerous Trojan Horse infections that try to hijack it or disguise themselves as it."